# Nuxt deployment with nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, pm2

I have recently tried to use Nuxt with my Vue projects for **server-side rendering (SSR)** . I was a bit confused about using the build file (dist folder) with nginx. 
in *Vue-CLI* after building Process in the dist folder, there was an index.html  that served as nginx index file in dist folder as root folder. Everything worked smoothly.
However, after building the Nuxt app, I get two subdirectories in dist folder : **server** and **client**.This is understandable since they are used  for **SSR** and **CSR** purposes. but I have no idea how to deploy it since the server folder have two index files: **index.spa.html** and **index.ssr.html**.
I tried to pass both of them as nginx index file  but to no avail.
I am unsure if it is even possible to do so since all the video I found online recommended using Nuxt with PM2 and reverse proxy configuration with nginx. 
PS: it seems deployment with nuxt-only dist folder is not possible and it needs the dependencies in node-modules . so any ideas ? what about --standalone ?